# TclError when calling a library in julia 0.3

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, julia

I am getting error as below when trying to call a library package called "Winston" which is for graph plotting purposes. Can any one suggest a solution?

```
julia> using Winston
ERROR: TclError("error initializing Tk: version conflict for package \"Tcl\": have 8.5.15, need 8.6")
 in init at /home/devanand/.julia/v0.3/Tk/src/tkwidget.jl:61
 in include at ./boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:128
 in include at ./boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:128
 in reload_path at loading.jl:152
 in _require at loading.jl:67
 in require at loading.jl:54
 in include at ./boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:128
 in include at ./boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:128
 in reload_path at loading.jl:152
 in _require at loading.jl:67
 in require at loading.jl:51
while loading /home/devanand/.julia/v0.3/Tk/src/tkwidget.jl, in expression starting on line 452
while loading /home/devanand/.julia/v0.3/Tk/src/Tk.jl, in expression starting on line 25
while loading /home/devanand/.julia/v0.3/Winston/src/tk.jl, in expression starting on line 1
while loading /home/devanand/.julia/v0.3/Winston/src/Winston.jl, in expression starting on line 2699
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message itself is pretty clear:

```
error initializing Tk: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.15, need 8.6
```

You've linked against Tk 8.6 (of some kind) yet you've linked against Tcl 8.5.15, which is not a combination that works (as Tk 8.6 uses some features of Tcl 8.6; Tk 8.5 *might* work with Tcl 8.6 though…) This linking might have happened at runtime (e.g., if things are installed as libtcl.so rather than the more-usually-recommended libtcl85.so or libtcl8.5.so, and similar for Tk) or might be more static than that, but the only way to fix it is to use a combination of libraries that works.

I *currently recommend* using Tcl and Tk of exactly the same version, and note that debugging library problems can be very hard. If you're lucky, you can use the `ldd` program to probe what libraries are actually linked into the executable, which can help guide what might be wrong. If things are working by dynamically locating and loading libraries, debugging the resulting mess can be highly challenging…

Comment: At least Tk gave a clear error at an early stage, rather than failing catastrophically at a random later time…

Comment: Luckily Julia has `Sys.dllist()` that gives you a list of all the libraries dynamically linked at runtime.

Comment: @DonalFellows : I tried checking in synaptic manager. Both the entries Tcl and Tcl 8.6 are green (installed) and Tk and Tk 8.6 too. Since I don't understand what you mean by linking etc, can you guide me on this issue. Should I install 'ldd'? Currently I am away from my machine.